# cannot Publish web app with Visual Studio 2019 and Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019

There are lots of examples of people having a similar problem to mine, but none of them are the problem that I'm having.

I'm running the Community edition of Visual Studio 2019 (maybe that's the problem).  I've already created a free Azure account using the same username/pw/email as the account that I have the version of Visual Studio installed as (note that Azure didn't used to support Core, but it does now).

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet) Microsoft Doc on how to create a ASP.NET Core web app with Azure.  I've created the project, and it's time to "publish" the web app.

Seems simple:  right click on the project >> Publish.  Here is the first window, where I should make sure that *App Service* is highlighted, then hit *Create New* and *Create Profile*.
[image]

In the next window I can either create my Azure account (which I already have) or sign in.  This option seems strange, being that I'm clearly already signed in.  Perhaps they mean signed into Azure?  In any case, I choose "Already have an account (sign in)" because I do.  If I were to choose the first option to create an account, it would tell me that I already have an account.
[image]

Next, it asks me to sign into Microsoft Visual Studio account (of which I'm already signed in -- my picture is on the upper right corner of the IDE).  I do it anyways:

[image]

Next I put in the password (I'll spare you this screenshot -- I showed the last one to illustrate that it wanted me to sign into Visual Studio when I'm already signed in), and...

Nothing.

It takes me back to the *App service* window.  According to the Microsoft doc, the wizard should continue to creating the resource group.

**What I've tried:**

- getting to "Publish" without signing into Visual Studio
- getting to "Publish" without signing into Azure (note that the email/pw associated with the Azure account is the same as my Visual Studio account, and I have access to the Azure account; I can go to the Dashboard, at least)
- and every variation of being signed into one and not the other or none or both
- repeated the entire thing while running Visual Studio 2019 as admin
- from the "Pick a publish target" window selecting *select existing* instead of *create new*.  It takes me to the same window that *create new* does
- instead of .NET Core, using just plain old .NET Framework 4.7.2

**What I *haven't* tried**

Uninstalling and reinstalling the Azure SDKs.  I'm scared if I do that, then Microsoft won't let me re-install them (because I already have once), and besides, this seems to be a problem with signing in.

Maybe there's some config that I'm missing, either in Visual Studio or Azure?
Maybe it's because I'm using the free Visual Studio version AND the free Azure?
Maybe it knows that I'm laid off and broke, and just wants to push the nail in?

I'm stuck.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions within the Azure Subscription to create a Resource Group?

Comment: Have you tried to create an App Service using the Azure Portal?

Comment: Have you solved your problem？ If you need further help, I will be happy to help you.

Comment: @JasonPan I am having this problem now. Did what OP did, what was suggested below, and still not working. Any idea?

Comment: @Farid Can you post your question ?

Comment: @JasonPan It's the exact same scenario. I signed in, and nothing happened. I'm on a pay-per-use account, doubt that would make any difference.

Comment: @JasonPan Nvm I got it to work. I signed out, clear the personal account cache, restarted my PC, and suddenly everything is working again. Sigh...

Comment: @Farid So my answer is useful to you. I am glad to hear that.

Comment: Tried all these tips, still not working for me :(

Answer (score 5):

This question involves both Azure accounts and Visual Studio.To deal with this problem, we can start with these two aspects.

First, we can publish the created project using FTP. If the project runs normally, it means that there is no problem with the free subscription account. The problem may appear on VS.

Second, we can `devenv.exe / resetuserdata` to clear the personal account cache information on Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Similar issue in VS2022 - resetuserdata works

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem, just enable yours directories in visual studio 2019.

[image: My example]

Thanks :)

Comment: BUT WHERE is this option?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

After 30 days of a free trial account, when you want to deploy for example a new Azure app service you can see the label "(disabled) free". This is why you cannot proceed with Visual Studio publishing anymore.

I had the same problem with you. I created a new Microsoft account and then a new Azure account. Now Visual Studio allows me to proceed with creating a new profile in order to publish my app.

I hope I helped you.